# objective c - execute animations in a while loop

Tags: objective-c, animation, while-loop

I am programming a memory game for the iPad with Xcode and i got a problem in that routine when the computer is processing a turn. when he hits a pair then he should have an other turn, thats why i need this method to have a big while loop, but when this loop is implemented, the animation to turn a card around is no more executed / shown.

### EDIT:

At first: Thanks for ur answer.
I think that i structured my program like u said, but i need some more concrete help please. I really dont know what to do next. I just tried to use an animatewithduration, but the animation was triggered instantly then, so i commented it off.
I uploaded my project to let u get a better insight what i did and it would be nice if u can help me with that. -> [myproject](http://www.multiupload.nl/51R4YQTVI3)

A more detailed description:
The app starts with a settings view on a tab bar. u can ignore it, just press the first tab to start the game. There is a collection view with 48 memory cards (24 pairs). for testing purposes they show the front image and not the backside. The user starts and has the first turn. He has to click on 2 cards, and they will move around to show the backside. If it is a pair, the player has an other turn, if not, then it is the computers turn now (the two cards are stored at the computer enemy's memory) and the user is no more able to touch cards.At the start of his turn, the computer looks in his memory if he has stored a pair already. if yes he takes the two cards and they should turn around and should have  an other turn. If not he will chose the first card by random and looks that in his memory if he knows where the second card lies. If the computer found no pair because he had no fittable cards in his memory and the two cards he choosed by random are also not a pair, its the players turn and the app waits until the player touches two cards.

That works very well until here, but now comes the problem. If the computer enemy matched a pair, he has an other turn. Thats why i used a while loop. But what do i have to do, to implement tat algorithm without a while loop?

code in that view controller looks like the following:

```
    NSLog(@"computer ist dran!");
//while(!playerVsCompViewController.isPlayersTurn)
//{
    NSLog(@"test!!!!");

    //sleep(1);
    //pruefen ob computer ein paar kennt
    // (Check whether the computer "knows" a pair)

    if([playerVsCompViewController.computerEnemy knowAPair])
    {
        //wenn spiel noch nicht zu ende...
        //(if game not to end)
    }
    else
    {
        //zufallszahl zum umdrehen der ersten karte
        //(random number to turn over the first card)

        int random = (arc4random() % [playerVsCompViewController.cards count]);
        HTWMyCustomCell *cell1 = [[playerVsCompViewController.cards objectAtIndex:random] parentCell];

        //erste karte umdrehen
        // (first turn card)

        [UIView transitionWithView:cell1 duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^
         {
             cell1.cellCard.showsFront = true;
             cell1.cellImage.image = cell1.cellCard.backImage;

             //wenn fertig soll zweite karte umgedreht werden
             //(when ready to begin second card will be turned over)
         } completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             //pruefen ob erste karte im paarkarte im gedaechtnis hat
             //(Look for pair for first card in memory)

             HTWCard *pairCard = [self memoriedPairCard:cell1.cellCard];

             //wenn die paarkarte dazu im gedaechtnis gefunden wurde
             //(when the pair was found in memory)

             if(pairCard != NULL)
             {
                 //zweite karte aufdecken
                 //(uncover second card)

                 [UIView transitionWithView:pairCard.parentCell duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^
                  {
                      pairCard.showsFront = true;
                      pairCard.parentCell.cellImage.image = pairCard.backImage;
                  } completion:^(BOOL finished)
                  {
                      //beide karten aus dem gedaechtnis loeschen
                      //(Delete both cards from the memory)

                      [self deleteCardesFromMemory:cell1.cellCard andSecondCard:pairCard];
                  }];
             }
             else
             {
                 //wenn keine passende karte gefunden in der memory gefunden wurde
                 //(if no matching found in the memory card was found)

                 //zweite karte zufaellig umdrehen
                 //(Turn second card randomly)

                 int random2 = (arc4random() % [playerVsCompViewController.cards count]);
                 HTWMyCustomCell *cell2 = [[playerVsCompViewController.cards objectAtIndex:random2] parentCell];
                 
                 [UIView transitionWithView:cell2 duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^
                  {
                      cell2.cellCard.showsFront = true;
                      cell2.cellImage.image = cell2.cellCard.backImage;
                  } completion:^(BOOL finished)
                  {
                      sleep(1);

                      //paerchen gefunden
                      //(pair found)

                      if(cell1.cellCard.frontImage == cell2.cellCard.frontImage)
                      {
                          //punkte an computer verteilen
                          //(distribute points to computer)
                          
                          //karten aus dem gedaechtnis loeschen
                          //(delete cards from the memory)

                          [self deleteCardesFromMemory:cell1.cellCard andSecondCard:cell2.cellCard];
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          //kein paerchen gefunden
                          //(found no up pairs)

                          //karten ins gedaechtnis speichern
                          //(save cards to memory)

                          [self updateMemory:cell1.cellCard];
                          [self updateMemory:cell2.cellCard];
                          playerVsCompViewController.isPlayersTurn = true;

                          //karten wieder zurueckdrehen
                          //(cards to turn back again)

                          [UIView transitionWithView:cell1 duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^
                           {
                               cell1.cellCard.showsFront = false;
                               cell1.cellImage.image = cell1.cellCard.frontImage;
                               
                           } completion:^(BOOL finished1)
                           {
                               cell2.cellCard.showsFront = false;
                               [UIView transitionWithView:cell2 duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^
                                {
                                    cell2.cellCard.showsFront = false;
                                    cell2.cellImage.image = cell2.cellCard.frontImage;
                                } completion:^(BOOL finished2)
                                {
                                    //wenn spiel noch nicht vorbei ist
                                    //spieler ist an der reihe
                                    //(if game is not over yet
                                    //player has its turn)

                                    playerVsCompViewController.isPlayersTurn = true;
                                }];
                           }];
                          
                      }// ende zufaellig paar getroffen (end coincidentally hit pair)
                  }]; // ende animation zweite karte (end animation second card)
             }
         }];
        
    }
//}
NSLog(@"computer ist fertig!");
```

Comment: What @Rob said below;  in iOS (and OS X), you *never* write polling code or code that uses a `while` loop to handle events and/or do animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing your project, it feels like you're trying to treat animations, which are inherently asynchronous, like synchronous operations. Unfortunately, wrapping a bunch of animations in a `while` loop just won't work. You have to adopt some asynchronous pattern for this if you want the completion of the animation of the computer's successful move with another move.

The simple solution is to simply have the final completion block of the computer's animation of the flipping of a successful match (whether `knowsAPair` succeeds, or a randomly card matched one in memory, or whether a second randomly picked card matched the first randomly picked card) then dispatch another call to the `processTurn` method to the main queue (to let the computer try again).

Some unrelated observations

1. In your `knowsAPair`, you were animating if it knew of a pair, but you weren't doing anything to delete the cards from your memory, nor trigger the running of the `processTurn` again. The routine had a few variables that were unnecessary and was continuing to look for matches even after the first match was found.
2. While letting the computer randomize cards, you didn't appear to be checking to see if (a) the card was already flipped; or that (b) the second card didn't match the first card.

---

The typical coding pattern would not be a `while` loop, but more of an event-driven pattern, triggered by the user's move (e.g. a gesture recognizer or button). You'd want this method to

- Checking some boolean class property which indicates whether user moves are to be accepted (turns out, you have such a property already) and, if not, provide some feedback that the user input is not permitted, but then exit immediately;
- Assuming that the class property indicated that user input was to be accepted, you'd then turn off that boolean class property to make sure further user input won't be accepted until the device is done doing the necessary animation and computer moves;
- Animate the user's move;
- Animate the computer's move(s), and if the computer gets another move, the final animation block of the current move should initiate the computer's next move; and when you're done,
- Turn back on the boolean property that says that user moves are permitted.

As an aside, I see you have a `sleep` statement in there. Instead of `sleep`, if you want to defer some animation, you should either do `dispatch_after` (or if it's a `UIView animateWithDuration`, use the rendition with the `delay` parameter). But doing a `sleep` on the main thread is strongly discouraged.

Hopefully that helps a little. Bottom line, move to event-driven, turn-based pattern, using some control property to indicate whether further user input should be accepted because animations take place asynchronously.

If I've misinterpreted what your game is doing (I was assuming some turn-based card game), you might want to edit your question and include a very brief narrative description of the game rules and what the UX should be.

Comment: thanks for ur answer,                                                                      i tried this code, but the animation was triggered instantly                                                                `[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^
             {
                 cell1.cellCard.showsFront = true;
                 cell1.cellImage.image = cell1.cellCard.backImage;
                 //wenn fertig soll zweite karte umgedreht werden
             } completion:^(BOOL finished){}`

Comment: @user2566570 Changing the image is not animatable, this you need to do `dispatch_after` with a nested `transitionWithView`.

Comment: downloaded it btw, u can delete it